# Intellij build different from maven build

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I compile an uber jar from the command line via `mvn package` and execute with `java -jar target/my-jar.jar`, it fails with some dependencies conflicts.

When I execute from run/debug configuration, using Intellij's make, everything is fine!

Is there something different about Intellij's classpath?  How would I go about figuring out the differences between the two builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out myself and learned a couple of things along the way.  The problem turned out to be my maven shade plugin which was using

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
```

Even if you exclude transitive dependencies religiously, that transformer will still concatenate classes defined transitively and can cause issues with hk2 not finding the class it needs to inject dependencies.  I was excluding some classes in order to prevent my application from running both Jersey 1 and Jersey 2.  Removing that line fixed things for me and matched the behavior in Intellij.

Some potential differences between the artifact produced by `mvn package` and running a build with Intellij:

- Intellij does not product a jar and thus, no META-INF directory.  When using jersey and maven shade plugin, the META-INF/services directory is often scanned by the hk2 dependency for dependency injection.
- Making a build in Intellij does not go through the maven lifecycle.  If you rely on a particular maven plugin or build step to run your application, you'll have to have it execute a maven lifecycle step instead of the IDE's make.
- There are slight scoping differences between Intellij (currently version 15) and maven.  I discovered this by comparing `mvn dependency:list -Dsort=true` and sorting the screen in Project Settings > modules > {your module} > dependencies (tab).
- There were some transitive dependencies found by maven that weren't in Intellij and vice versa.  I used both `dependency:list` and `dependency:tree -Dincludes=the.groupIid:the.artifact` to track down where some transitive dependencies came from.

Comment: I was getting different results when running in the IDE compared to compiled jar with maven. The answer was contained within the results of `mvn dependency:list -Dsort=true`